# android gravity center not working in textview

Tags: android, textview, gravity

I created 4 textviews programmatically and i added it in my layout, i have one problem gravity center property not working.i mean when i increase my textview's text size gravity Center Repealed.default text size is 14dp
Please check my code snippet.

```
private class DigitView extends TextView {
    public DigitView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DigitView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DigitView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        // If selected draw the accent
        if (isSelected()) {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pincode_background_border_select);

        }
        else
        {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pincode_background_border_unselect);
        }

    }

}




 for (int i = 0; i < mDigits; i++) {
        DigitView digitView = new DigitView(getContext());
        digitView.setWidth(valueInPixels);
        digitView.setHeight(valueInPixels);
        digitView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        digitView.setTextSize(mDigitTextSize);
        digitView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            digitView.setElevation(mDigitElevation);
        }

        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (i > 0) {
            lp.leftMargin = 10; // margin goes here. Use marginStart instead to support right-to-left layouts
        }
        childView.addView(digitView, lp);
    }
```

and this is a my layout xml code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_Container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_Container_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>



my_Container_child is my layout
```

[this is a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwtUj.png)

what am i doing wrong? if anyone knows solution please help me 
thanks

Comment: Add layout gravity property to LinearLayout

Comment: do you want text within textView in center or textView within linearLayout to be centered? Also which layout is childView?

Comment: @yogi i updated my  question.please see my   result image

Comment: @ShadowDroid Droidi updated my  question.please see my   result image

Comment: give wrap_content property for height and width for textview  i think it will work

Comment: I would like to know which layout is childView out of the two linear layout? Also type of LayoutParam you are using...check the import for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.It will work...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_Container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
   >


    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/my_Container_child"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tryed it but nothink changed .this is a my result  http://s29.postimg.org/4hzcafu2f/Capture.png @Naveen

Answer (score 0):

Dont give fix height and width to textview

i think error is in this code

```
 DigitView digitView = new DigitView(getContext());
 digitView.setWidth(valueInPixels);
 digitView.setHeight(valueInPixels);
```